# This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window

Tags: android

I have a problem with my Navigation Drawer.
my project First run by splash page and Then show Navigation Drawer.
When I compile my application the following error messages :

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: ir.mosayebtorabi.sapp, PID: 4793
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.mosayebtorabi.sapp/com.loridic.ir.loridic.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:201)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
     at com.loridic.ir.loridic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

activity_splash_screen.xml Contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
tools:context="com.loridic.ir.loridic.SplashScreen">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/lorvajeh"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
    android:contentDescription="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/welcomeText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/welcome_screen"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

activity_splash_screen class Contains:

```
package com.loridic.ir.loridic;
import android.app.Activity;`
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
Handler handler;
public static Activity fa;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    fa = this;
    ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.image);
    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.welcomeText);

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.splashtransition);
    iv.startAnimation(animation);
    tv.startAnimation(animation);
    Splashregister();


}

public void Splashregister() {
    handler = new Handler();
    {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fa.finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        }, 4000);

    }
}
}
```

styles.xml Contains:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

MainActivity class Contains:

```
package com.loridic.ir.loridic;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
FrameLayout frameLayout;
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    frameLayout=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frmlayoutview);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.SentWord) {
        FragmentTransaction ft=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frmlayoutview,new FragmentClassAddWord());
        ft.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.Target) {
        FragmentTransaction ft=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frmlayoutview,new FragmentClassAbout());
        ft.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.PersonalInformation) {
        FragmentTransaction ft=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frmlayoutview,new FragmentClassRegistername());
        ft.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.Share) {
        FragmentTransaction ft=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frmlayoutview,new FragmentClassShare());
        ft.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.About) {
        FragmentTransaction ft=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frmlayoutview,new FragmentClassMaker());
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

MainActivity xml Contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml Contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.loridic.ir.loridic">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="LoreVajeh"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activityaddword" />
    <activity android:name=".Activityregistername" />
    <activity android:name=".Activityabout" />
    <activity android:name=".Activitymaker" />
    <activity android:name=".Activityshareapp" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post app_bar_main layout

Answer (score 2):

As you are supplying a `toolbar` in your `MainActivity` you need to turn the default one off in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

e.g.

```xml
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Comment: I uploaded AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: And the `.MainActivity` does not have the right theme it should have a theme of "NoActionBar" as the error say `Unable to start activity ... ComponentInfo{ir.mosayebtorabi.sapp/com.loridic.ir.loridic.MainActivity} `. You have done it for the `SplashScreen` just do the same for `MainActivity`